# How can I define a Wine application to handle special links?

Tags: gnome, 21.04, url, xdg-open

*Is it possible to activate a `wine` application when I click a URL having a specific method?*

More specifically my question is this:

I have used `amule` in the past to handle `ed2k:` links. When I clicked an `ed2k:…` link on a web page, `amule` was handling that link. Later, I decided that *eMule* under *Wine* would be more efficient; so, I removed the `amule` Ubuntu package. Now, when I click to a URL like the following, nothing happens:

```
ed2k://|file|ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso|2818738176|9F2FFA4B119C14F7539D4FB92D6B64EE|/
```

Similarly, the

```
xdg-open 'ed2k://|file|ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso|2818738176|9F2FFA4B119C14F7539D4FB92D6B64EE|/'
```

command returns the error: `gio: ed2k://…/: The specified location is not supported`

So, how can I add support to GNOME to open that specific URL with a specific command, like:

```
nohup /usr/bin/wine /home/my_user/opt/eMule/emule.exe >/tmp/emule.out 2>/tmp/emule.err &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling around and with some trial and error, I found the following solution:

First, define the `wine emule.exe` "application" by creating a `~/.local/share/applications/emule.desktop` file with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Name=eMule v0.60c wine
Type=Application
Terminal=false
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/ed2k
Exec=/usr/bin/wine /home/my_user/opt/eMule/emule.exe %u
Icon=/home/my_user/opt/eMule/EMule_mascot.svg
Path=/home/my_user/opt/eMule/
Categories=Network;P2P;
Comment=A client for the eD2k network
Comment[fr]=Un client pour le réseau eD2k
Comment[tr]=eD2k ağı için istemci
Comment[it]=Un client per la rete eD2k
Keywords=ed2k emule amule
```

<sub>**Note:** You can download the `EMule_mascot.svg` file from: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/EMule_mascot.svg</sub>

Then, run the command

```
xdg-mime default emule.desktop x-scheme-handler/ed2k
```

to add the line `x-scheme-handler/ed2k=emule.desktop` to the end of file `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

After that, you can click to any link starting with `ed2k:` to launch your newly defined application with the link as parameter. Also, the

```
xdg-open 'ed2k://|file|ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso|2818738176|9F2FFA4B119C14F7539D4FB92D6B64EE|/'
```

command will run as expected.