# How to configure Ubuntu to start windows application pinned to the dock and to associate files to that app?

Tags: wine, winetricks

I have installed the latest wine and winetricks following the instructions on the official winehq wiki: [wine install instructions](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) and [winetricks install instructions](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks)

Then I successfully installed Ableton Live 10 following [these](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=39289) instructions again on winehq site. I started the application by launching the `explorer.exe` like this:

```
wine64 explorer.exe
```

and then locating and double clicking the Ableton Live's executable from the explorer's interface. It runs fine, then I pinned the program's icon to the Ubuntu's applications dock and quited the instance. But when I try to start the program by clicking the icon in the dock the program never starts. There is no error message shown.

Also when I click on a file that is expected to get launched with Ableton I get a window with the following error message:
"There is no Windows program configured to open this type of file", though from the context menu you can choose the "Open with Ableton Live 10" option.

I also can't even start Ableton from Ubuntu's terminal with the command!!!

```
wine "C:\ProgramData\Ableton\Live 10 Suite\Program\Ableton Live 10 Suite.exe"
```

Which generates the following log:

```
059c:fixme:file:NtFsControlFile FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT semi-stub
059c:fixme:file:NtFsControlFile FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT semi-stub
ERROR: unknown file sink (C:\users\C0DEGURU\AppData\Roaming\Ableton\Live 10.1.18\Preferences\Log.txt)
ERROR: unknown file sink (C:\users\C0DEGURU\AppData\Roaming\Ableton\Live 10.1.18\Preferences\Log.txt)
ERROR: unknown file sink (C:\users\C0DEGURU\AppData\Roaming\Ableton\Live 10.1.18\Preferences\Log.txt)
ERROR: unknown file sink (C:\users\C0DEGURU\AppData\Roaming\Ableton\Live 10.1.18\Preferences\Log.txt)
ERROR: unknown file sink (C:\users\C0DEGURU\AppData\Roaming\Ableton\Live 10.1.18\Preferences\Log.txt)
0058:fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl returning zero-filled buffer for IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS
059c:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
05a0:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (00000000066EFE10 0000000000000000): stub
0058:fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl returning zero-filled buffer for IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS
05a4:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Pro Audio",000000000A90FD70): stub
05a8:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Pro Audio",000000000AB0FD70): stub
05ac:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Pro Audio",000000000AD0FD70): stub
05b0:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Pro Audio",000000000AF0FD70): stub
05b4:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Pro Audio",000000000B10FD70): stub
05b8:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Pro Audio",000000000B30FD70): stub
05bc:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Pro Audio",000000000B50FD70): stub
05c0:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Pro Audio",000000000B70FD70): stub
05f4:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Pro Audio",000000000B90FD70): stub
0588:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Pro Audio",000000000BB0FD70): stub
05ec:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Pro Audio",000000000BD0FD70): stub
05c8:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Pro Audio",000000000BF0FD70): stub
05d0:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Pro Audio",000000000C10FD70): stub
05e8:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Pro Audio",000000000C30FD70): stub
0594:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000021FD70 0000000000000000): stub
```

### What program/service is responsible for the file associations of Wine applications and how to configure it?

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Wayland

Wine version: wine-8.0

Winetricks version: 20230212-next

Comment: Sounds like a good question to ask on the Wine support site. The question I would be asking there is can an app that needs wine to be used be started from the dock?

Comment: My answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1365731/855322 may help. If it does, be sure to upvote. :)

Comment: @FedKad you answer could be helpful only if I manage to find out how to start the app from a terminal. The standard way just fails. I mean the official documentation says that `wine "C:\ProgramData\Ableton\Live 10 Suite\Program\Ableton Live 10 Suite.exe"` would launch the application, but it doesn't in my case. The only way I can launch it by clicking the app from the `winefile` browser or `wine explorer.exe`.

Comment: @FedKad I have updated my question